# Создание объекта, зависящего от объекта из другого activity

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно создать массив weeks от значения, введенного пользователем в другой activity. Сохраняю это значение через SharedPreferences:

```
public int getNumberOfWeeks() {
        loadText();
        return Integer.parseInt(setNumberOfWeeks.getText().toString());
    }

    private void saveText() {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString("saved_text", setNumberOfWeeks.getText().toString());
        ed.apply();
    }

    private void loadText() {
        SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString("saved_text", "");
        setNumberOfWeeks.setText(savedText);
    }
```

Пытался сделать getter для EditText, но столкнулся с невозможностью использовать static поля для getPrefernces(), создал объект класса settings в activity main, все равно не работает, предполагаю, что он не может получить значение, так как оно не загружено, пытался вызвать load в getter, ничего не вышло. Как лучше мне поступить?

Comment: Лучше использовать intent.PutExtra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)` зависит от контекста - для каждой активности сохраняется отдельный файл.
Замените на `getSharedPreferences("pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE)`
где `pref_name` - имя для преференса какое хотите.
Так в обеих активностях по одному и тому же имени вы сможете читать и писать преференсы из одного файла.

Comment: А каким образом тогда мне вызывать в activity main метод get? Добавить в loadText аргумент SharedPreferences?

Comment: Не совсем понял о чём вы? Точно также получаете объект `SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE)` и берёте из него значение.